# Is there a way to align ipywidgets checkbox and radiobutton?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, ipywidgets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi2Y9.png)

I'm trying to align ipywidgets checkbox and radiobuttons. The checkboxes are children of a VBox container, and the VBoxes are children of a HBox. However, I want the user to only be able to select one item under the groupby column, because I want to do a Pandas dataframe groupby.

If I do it just using checkboxes, the layout is no problem but the problem arises in that the user may choose to select more than once due to the non intuitive interface, as shown here: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4uds.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.